# how to convert byte array to mp4 file file MediaElment windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

Why it's doesn't work?

```
using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    using (DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(ms))
    {
        byte[] video = await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
        writer.WriteBytes(video);
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        await writer.FlushAsync();
        writer.DetachStream();
    }
    ms.Seek(0);
    MediaStreamSource l = new MediaStreamSource();
    IMediaStreamDescriptor o = new VideoStreamDescriptor();
    MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
    media.SetSource(ms, "MP4");

    PlayFiles.stat[folder + "/" + filename] = media;
}
```

I think problem in string
media.SetSource(ms, "MP4");
Please, HELP

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that you're storing asynchronously.  The latter portion of the program has no way of knowing when the async operation is finished.  So potentially, you're trying to open a file that the program hasn't finished writing yet.